# sharepoint 2013 visual studio workflow listitem dynamicvalue - get field value

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2013

this is what I did so far:

1. I'm using **LookupSPListItem** to get the current listItem out of the currentList.
2. The Result value is of type **DynamicValue**.

[image]

So far so good.

But how do I ***access specific values inside the resulting DynamicValue variable***?
Unfortunately debugging my workflow doesn't work for some reasons... so I cannot have a look at the variable :(

I do not want to extract every single field on its own... that's too much work.

Comment: Show some code of what you tried, it should help. I had huge issues getting those lookup fields to work, but with some code I may find your problem.

Comment: code like in "xaml"? this is a declarative workflow... For clarification I added a screenshot of the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access specific properties inside **DynamicValue** variable depends on the JSON structure it has parsed. But for example if you had something as below:

```
{
 "d" : {
     "results" : [
           { "Title" : "Example1" },
           { "Title" : "Example2" } 
     ]
 }
}
```

You can access those using the `GetDynamicValueProperty` activity (type Microsoft.Activities.dynamicValue) with

`PropertyName` as `"d/results(1)/Title"`

`Source` as your dynamic variable

`Result` with the variable you want to save the output to.

With the above query it would return *Example2*. In your case the result will be 1 element array, so you can query for example ID using *"d/results(0)/ID"*